# Adding non-android xml file to android project

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have problems with adding a non-android xml file init.xml to android project in Eclipse. This file is used to initialize some simulation process, which is not connected with android. Eclipse doesn't recognize it if simply put it into project directory and write something like

```
File file = new File("init.xml");
```

Should I declare the file in some specific way or put it into other directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this file inside the `assets` folder and then you can access this file by using [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) and [getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets%28%29).

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream instream = assetManager.open("init.xml");
```

Comment: What if I need to use it like a field of type File? I have a method SimulationEngine.init(File file);

Comment: HI paresh : off topic , and i am in blacked_state : can you please tell me why we use this file in android .
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcjdtychzahimeb/toParesh.png

Comment: @TusharPandey no idea, BTW what's that `blacked_state` exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Put it into the `/res/xml` directory and access it as a resource with `Resources.getXML()`.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

You should put these files in the `assets/` directory and then access them via the [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it on the assets folder, to get it from there just use this:

```
Activity.getAssets().open(...) //with your file..
```

Answer (score -1):

you can put the file res/layout
and dont forget 2 give extension .xml  i hope it would be already wd extension .xml

and you can acces that xml on source page like

(R.layout.xml name )