# Accessing non-android xml file in android project

Tags: java, android, xml, file

Usually I can put an xml-file (of non-android format, the same would be if I need, f.e., to use .txt file) into my project directory and use it by

```
  File file = new File("init.xml");
```

This doesn't work with android project, so I need a solution.

P.S. Asset manager doesn't work in this case, because I need to work exactly with a field of File type, but AM only provides the following method

```
InputStream open(String fileName);
```

Comment: Why don't you edit your other question, instead of adding a new one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181787/adding-non-android-xml-file-to-android-project/8181832#8181832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in your res folder and access it with `R.foo.bar` The path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can place the file in the resource path and use something like the following to access it

`InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.myfile);`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your file? I think it'll work if you put it in a "raw" folder in your project.